# Digital Signature - Signing Cab File - validation for Auto installation

Tags: digital-signature, bluebird, private-key, windows-mobile-6.5, cab

I got this scenario for one of my projects.
I wanted to my program to be auto-run to be installed once after the mobile device being hard-reset. (Mobile device 6.5)
It should be auto-ran if i put the installation file (.cab file) in the startup folder according to the manufacturer.
However, the device's manufacturer have built some security mechanism on validate the cab file.(Only the signed .exe file zipped in a signed cab file can be ran automatically). Both digital signature are different.

1. I have .cert and .pvk for signing the cab file.
2. I have only .cert for signing exe file but do not have the .pvk file.

By any meaning, is there any other walk-around method to make the happening of the auto installation after hard-reset?

Please advise and thanks.

Comment: Would your certificate chain require a new root cert be put on the device first after a hard reset before your cab would be trusted?  Would the device have to re-enroll to an AD source before your cert would be trusted?

Comment: 1)Would your certificate chain require a new root cert be put on the device first after a hard reset before your cab would be trusted?
** No need, the hard-reset would not wipe out the certificate, unless i remove it manually in earlier **

2) Would the device have to re-enroll to an AD source before your cert would be trusted? 
** No need as well, the device is completely offline during installation**

if i have way to get their .pvk file for signing the .exe file, then i should be able to make the auto-installation works.

Comment: By Hard reset I thought you meant factory reset.  I am assuming that you did not create the win mobile 6.5 os image yourself, so I would ask the question in the context of your exact hardware/OS Image and if you are enrolling the device in an AD or similar certificate system and how user accounts participate in that enrollment.